# Make a conjunction of expression from a list

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-manipulation

I have a rather silly question, I assume:

I have a (nested) list of polynomials that I made from a matrix with the `Minors` command and I would like to make them into polynomial equations with a conjunction. So for instance, say the list is equal to `{{f1,f2},{f3,f4}}`, where `f1,f2,f3,f4` are polynomials, then I want the following conjunction:

```
f1 == 0 && f2 == 0 && f3 == 0 && f4 == 0
```

I would like this to be as automated as possible. I wasn't able to find the appropriate way to do this yet. Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 6):

Here's one way:

```
f = Flatten[{{f1, f2}, {f3, f4}}];
And @@ Thread[f == 0]

f1 == 0 && f2 == 0 && f3 == 0 && f4 == 0
```

The Thread gives you a list of four equations, each equal to zero. The @@ applies the And function to the head of the List, essentially transforming the list into a collection of Ands.

Answer (score 3):

```
f = Flatten[{{f1, f2}, {f3, f4}}];

Inner[Equal, f, 0 & /@ f, And]
```

> f1 == 0 && f2 == 0 && f3 == 0 && f4 == 0

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a somewhat general case, where the rhs for each list is possibly different and different operators are applied to every list, the following segment

```
With[{minors = {{f1, f2}, {f3, f4}}},
 Block[{rhs = {{a, b}, {c, d}}, opers = {And, Or}},
  oper @@ MapThread[#3 @@ Thread[Equal[#1, #2]] &, {minors, rhs, opers}]
  ]
 ]
```

returns

> ```
> oper[f1 == a && f2 == b, f3 == c || f4 == d]
> ```

When `rhs={0,0},{0,0}}` and `opers={And,And}`, `oper=And` then we get the requested output ie

> ```
> f1 == 0 && f2 == 0 && f3 == 0 && f4 == 0
> ```